# How to allow only certain users to login

Tags: login

I have looked but could not find either a plugin or code that allows only certin users to login in to my wordpress site e.g wan, velma, bob and no other.

Does anyone know how to do this.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: How many users do you have to block out?
You could simply disable other users.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Steffen, I want this for security reasons, to prevent brute force break-ins, it is impossible to deny access to every ip address that is trying to access my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to set your specific list of users to admin, and use [Theme my Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) to redirect admin users to the page you want to see, and to set all other roles to redirect to an invalid page which they can't have access.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question--have you tried just disabling registration (Settings > General > Uncheck "anyone can register")? Once registration is disabled, you can just delete any accounts that you don't want logging in.

Does this solve your problem, or is there some additional requirement?

If you're worried about login security in general, I'd suggest a two-factor authentication helper, like Duo: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duo-wordpress/ Basically, it requires that you answer a phone call, or type in a code that's texted to your phone before it lets you log in. Pretty cool! I personally had some trouble getting the Duo plugin to play nice with some custom login stuff I'd written, but if you don't have any other login security plugins, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/)